# First for-callback prints future list almost every time, second onComplete-callback rarely returns success (never failure)

Tags: scala, concurrency, callback, future

I'm going through some Future examples. I have a Future which retrieves a list from a method. I call two different kinds of callbacks, a Foreach callback and an onComplete callback just to try them out.

- The Foreach callback nearly every time returns the list.
- The onComplete callback rarely returns SUCCESS even though the For callback has returned the list.
- The onComplete callback never returns FAILURE.

Can someone please explain to me what's happening?

I understand that the callbacks do execute concurrently, and do not have an order. But if the Future is returning the list to Foreach andthe onComplete callback has executed before the Foreach and Future and it tried to get the list from an unsuccessful Future, shouldn't the onComplete callback return FAILURE?

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object FuturesExampleObj extends App {

  println("Using Future to retrieve list\n")
  val l: Future[List[String]] = Future {
    getList()
  }

  println("FOR CALLBACK --------------------\n")

  l foreach {
    items =>
      for(item <- items) println(s"foreach item : $item")
      println("\n")
  }

  println("onComplete CALLBACK --------------------\n")

  l onComplete {
    case Success(i) => println(s"SUCCESS : $i")
    case Failure(i) => println(s"FAILURE : $i")
  }

  def getList(): List[String] ={
    val list = ("a" :: "b" :: "c" :: "d" :: "e":: Nil)
    list
  }
}
```

**Result Example 1 (Common)**

```
Using Future to retrieve list

FOR CALLBACK --------------------

onComplete CALLBACK --------------------

foreach item : a
foreach item : b
foreach item : c
foreach item : d
foreach item : e



Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Result Example 2 (uncommon)**

```
Using Future to retrieve list

FOR CALLBACK --------------------

onComplete CALLBACK --------------------


Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Result Example 3 (very rare)**

Basically onComplete never returns SUCCESS or FAILURE. On occasion, very rarely, it will return "SUCCESS: " + list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have to explicitly block on the future.
In your case, the main thread terminates before `onComplete` completion and sometimes before `l foreach ..` is finished.

Please add:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val listF = l foreach {
  items =>
    for(item <- items) println(s"foreach item : $item")
    println("\n")
}

Await.result(listF, 5 seconds)
```

That way you will wait for the completion of this future.

If you want to wait for `onComplete`, you need to use `Thread.sleep` (add it after the `onComplete`, for example:

```
l onComplete {
   case Success(i) => println(s"SUCCESS : $i")
   case Failure(i) => println(s"FAILURE : $i")
}

Thread.sleep(3000)
```

`onComplete` runs on some thread in the ExecutionContext, whereas `Await` runs on the current thread, and blocks it until it completes or the specified timeout is exceeded.
Hence `onComplete` is nonblocking and `Await` is blocking.

With `onComplete` we are not blocking for the result from the `Future` but instead, we will receive a callback for either a `Success` or a `Failure`.

`Thread.sleep()` is blocking our main thread so that we can see the asynchronous result from the future.

Please note that you should not use `Await.result` in production code, it's used for testing the output of the Future. 
In addition, you will most certainly not use `Thread.sleep()` but instead "react" to the result returned by the future.

Usually, you'll have some REST API call or another service which runs and waits for the future to complete.

Comment: If the Future result is required, but the callback does not receive the result in time, what can be done to make sure that the result is eventually returned? Is there a way to just retry?

Comment: `onComplete` doesn't return any future, that's why you can do `Await` on it. to make sure it's finished, you can use for-comprehensions (look for more info here - https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

Comment: Correction - onComplete doesn't return any future, that's why you *can not* do Await.  Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is the thread of the App finishes before the `Future` finishes.

Just add `Await.ready(l, Duration.Inf).value.get` at the and of your program.

**Do this only for testing!**

Comment: I done what you suggested, but I used Thread.sleep(). Why does the main thread not depend on the completion of onComplete before it exits?

Comment: they are not related. If you increase the `Thread.sleep()`, it will work.

Comment: What happens if I have multiple callbacks that I need to return the Future value, but I do not want to wait the program?

Comment: you would compose them and return a single Future. check for example https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-use-multiple-scala-futures-in-for-comprehension-loop

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll check that out. Also, would there ever be a requirement for there to be multiple callbacks for a single Future? I can't think of a scenario but I'm curious.